# Problema al usar fetch en una aplicación de Shopify

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, fetch, autenticación, shopify

Estoy construyendo una aplicación en shopify que consuma una API de un sistema que tengo para generación de guías de envío.
El problema es que cuando quiero hacer una petición fetch me marca el siguiente error:

```
2023-04-18 02:17:51 | backend  | [shopify-app/INFO] Running validateAuthenticatedSession
2023-04-18 02:17:51 | backend  | [shopify-app/INFO] Session was not valid. Redirecting to /api/auth?shop=undefined | {shop: undefined}
2023-04-18 02:17:51 | backend  | [shopify-api/ERROR] Missing Authorization header, was the request made with authenticatedFetch? | {isOnline: false}                                                                                                                              
2023-04-18 02:17:51 | backend  | [shopify-app/ERROR] No shop provided to redirect to auth
```

Cuando quito el archivo y la petición fetch ya no me marca el error, pero no me deja hacer peticiones a mi API.

El archivo de donde hago las peticiones es: ***apiClient.js*** y el codigo es:

```
const API_KEY =
    'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6Ikp...';

const apiClient = {
    baseURL: 'https://api-test.shopeenvios.com/',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: API_KEY,
    },
};

export async function getDataShopeAPI(endpoint, params) {
    try {
        const queryString = new URLSearchParams(params).toString();
        const response = await fetch(`${apiClient.baseURL}${endpoint}?${queryString}`, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: apiClient.headers,
        });

        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`HTTP error: ${response.status}`);
        }

        const data = await response.json();
        return data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data from API:', error);
        throw error;
    }
}

export async function postDataShopeAPI(endpoint, data) {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(`${apiClient.baseURL}${endpoint}`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: apiClient.headers,
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
        });

        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`HTTP error: ${response.status}`);
        }

        const responseData = await response.json();
        return responseData;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error posting data to API:', error);
        throw error;
    }
}
```

Y el codigo de la interfaz es el siguiente:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { getDataShopeAPI } from '../api/apiClient';

function HistorialEnvios() {
    const [paqueteria, setPaqueteria] = useState('estafeta');
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const paqueterias = ['estafeta', 'fedex', 'minutes', 'dhl'];

    useEffect(() => {
        if (paqueteria) {
            const fetchHistorial = async () => {
                try {
                    const endpoint = `${paqueteria}/historial`;
                    const params = {};
                    const response = await getDataShopeAPI(endpoint, params);
                    setData(response);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error('Error al obtener datos:', error);
                }
            };
            fetchHistorial();
        }
    }, [paqueteria]);

    const handlePaqueteriaChange = (newPaqueteria) => {
        setPaqueteria(newPaqueteria);
    };

    return (
        <div className='contenido'>
            <div className='body mt-3'>
                <h3 className='text-center'>Historial de Envíos</h3>
            </div>
            <div className='hr-container mt-2'>
                <hr />
            </div>
            <div className='d-flex justify-content-center flex-wrap mt-4 grupo'>
                {paqueterias.map((item) => (
                    <button
                        key={item}
                        type='button'
                        className={`opciones btn btn-light ${paqueteria === item.toLowerCase() ? 'active-opc' : ''}`}
                        onClick={() => handlePaqueteriaChange(item.toLowerCase())}
                    >
                        {item === 'MINUTES' ? '99 MINUTOS' : item.toUpperCase()}
                    </button>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default HistorialEnvios;
```

La configuración de shopify es la siguiente, ***shopify.js***:

```
import { BillingInterval, LATEST_API_VERSION } from "@shopify/shopify-api";
import { shopifyApp } from "@shopify/shopify-app-express";
import { SQLiteSessionStorage } from "@shopify/shopify-app-session-storage-sqlite";
import { restResources } from "@shopify/shopify-api/rest/admin/2023-01";

const DB_PATH = `${process.cwd()}/database.sqlite`;

// The transactions with Shopify will always be marked as test transactions, unless NODE_ENV is production.
// See the ensureBilling helper to learn more about billing in this template.
const billingConfig = {
  "My Shopify One-Time Charge": {
    // This is an example configuration that would do a one-time charge for $5 (only USD is currently supported)
    amount: 5.0,
    currencyCode: "USD",
    interval: BillingInterval.OneTime,
  },
};

const shopify = shopifyApp({
  api: {
    apiVersion: LATEST_API_VERSION,
    restResources,
    billing: undefined, // or replace with billingConfig above to enable example billing
  },
  auth: {
    path: "/api/auth",
    callbackPath: "/api/auth/callback",
  },
  webhooks: {
    path: "/api/webhooks",
  },
  // This should be replaced with your preferred storage strategy
  sessionStorage: new SQLiteSessionStorage(DB_PATH),
});

export default shopify;
```

El ***index.js*** es:

```
// @ts-check
import { join } from 'path';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import express from 'express';
import serveStatic from 'serve-static';

import shopify from './shopify.js';
import productCreator from './product-creator.js';
import GDPRWebhookHandlers from './gdpr.js';

const PORT = parseInt(process.env.BACKEND_PORT || process.env.PORT, 10);

const STATIC_PATH =
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? `${process.cwd()}/frontend/dist` : `${process.cwd()}/frontend/`;

const app = express();

// Set up Shopify authentication and webhook handling
app.get(shopify.config.auth.path, shopify.auth.begin());
app.get(shopify.config.auth.callbackPath, shopify.auth.callback(), shopify.redirectToShopifyOrAppRoot());
app.post(shopify.config.webhooks.path, shopify.processWebhooks({ webhookHandlers: GDPRWebhookHandlers }));

// If you are adding routes outside of the /api path, remember to
// also add a proxy rule for them in web/frontend/vite.config.js

app.use('/api/*', shopify.validateAuthenticatedSession());

app.use(express.json());

app.get('/api/products/count', async (_req, res) => {
    const countData = await shopify.api.rest.Product.count({
        session: res.locals.shopify.session,
    });
    res.status(200).send(countData);
});

app.get('/api/products/create', async (_req, res) => {
    let status = 200;
    let error = null;

    try {
        await productCreator(res.locals.shopify.session);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(`Failed to process products/create: ${e.message}`);
        status = 500;
        error = e.message;
    }
    res.status(status).send({ success: status === 200, error });
});

app.use(serveStatic(STATIC_PATH, { index: false }));

app.use('/*', shopify.ensureInstalledOnShop(), async (_req, res, _next) => {
    return res
        .status(200)
        .set('Content-Type', 'text/html')
        .send(readFileSync(join(STATIC_PATH, 'index.html')));
});

app.listen(PORT);
```

y mis archivos de hooks que tengo duda si se deben de configurar son:

***useAppQuery.js***

```
import { useAuthenticatedFetch } from "./useAuthenticatedFetch";
import { useMemo } from "react";
import { useQuery } from "react-query";

/**
 * A hook for querying your custom app data.
 * @desc A thin wrapper around useAuthenticatedFetch and react-query's useQuery.
 *
 * @param {Object} options - The options for your query. Accepts 3 keys:
 *
 * 1. url: The URL to query. E.g: /api/widgets/1`
 * 2. fetchInit: The init options for fetch.  See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#parameters
 * 3. reactQueryOptions: The options for `useQuery`. See: https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/useQuery
 *
 * @returns Return value of useQuery.  See: https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/useQuery.
 */
export const useAppQuery = ({ url, fetchInit = {}, reactQueryOptions }) => {
  const authenticatedFetch = useAuthenticatedFetch();
  const fetch = useMemo(() => {
    return async () => {
      const response = await authenticatedFetch(url, fetchInit);
      return response.json();
    };
  }, [url, JSON.stringify(fetchInit)]);

  return useQuery(url, fetch, {
    ...reactQueryOptions,
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
  });
};
```

***useAuthenticatedFetch.js***

```
import { authenticatedFetch } from '@shopify/app-bridge-utils';
import { useAppBridge } from '@shopify/app-bridge-react';
import { Redirect } from '@shopify/app-bridge/actions';

/**
 * A hook that returns an auth-aware fetch function.
 * @desc The returned fetch function that matches the browser's fetch API
 * See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API
 * It will provide the following functionality:
 *
 * 1. Add a `X-Shopify-Access-Token` header to the request.
 * 2. Check response for `X-Shopify-API-Request-Failure-Reauthorize` header.
 * 3. Redirect the user to the reauthorization URL if the header is present.
 *
 * @returns {Function} fetch function
 */
export function useAuthenticatedFetch() {
    const app = useAppBridge();
    const fetchFunction = authenticatedFetch(app);

    return async (uri, options) => {
        const response = await fetchFunction(uri, options);
        checkHeadersForReauthorization(response.headers, app);
        return response;
    };
}

function checkHeadersForReauthorization(headers, app) {
    if (headers.get('X-Shopify-API-Request-Failure-Reauthorize') === '1') {
        const authUrlHeader = headers.get('X-Shopify-API-Request-Failure-Reauthorize-Url') || `/api/auth`;

        const redirect = Redirect.create(app);
        redirect.dispatch(
            Redirect.Action.REMOTE,
            authUrlHeader.startsWith('/') ? `https://${window.location.host}${authUrlHeader}` : authUrlHeader
        );
    }
}
```

mi configuración de vite. es:

import { defineConfig } from "vite";

```
import { dirname } from "path";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";
import https from "https";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

if (
  process.env.npm_lifecycle_event === "build" &&
  !process.env.CI &&
  !process.env.SHOPIFY_API_KEY
) {
  console.warn(
    "\nBuilding the frontend app without an API key. The frontend build will not run without an API key. Set the SHOPIFY_API_KEY environment variable when running the build command.\n"
  );
}

const proxyOptions = {
  target: `http://127.0.0.1:${process.env.BACKEND_PORT}`,
  changeOrigin: false,
  secure: true,
  ws: false,
};

const host = process.env.HOST
  ? process.env.HOST.replace(/https?:\/\//, "")
  : "localhost";

let hmrConfig;
if (host === "localhost") {
  hmrConfig = {
    protocol: "ws",
    host: "localhost",
    port: 64999,
    clientPort: 64999,
  };
} else {
  hmrConfig = {
    protocol: "wss",
    host: host,
    port: process.env.FRONTEND_PORT,
    clientPort: 443,
  };
}

export default defineConfig({
  root: dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)),
  plugins: [react()],
  define: {
    "process.env.SHOPIFY_API_KEY": JSON.stringify(process.env.SHOPIFY_API_KEY),
  },
  resolve: {
    preserveSymlinks: true,
  },
  server: {
    host: "localhost",
    port: process.env.FRONTEND_PORT,
    hmr: hmrConfig,
    proxy: {
      "^/(\\?.*)?$": proxyOptions,
      "^/api(/|(\\?.*)?$)": proxyOptions,
    },
  },
});
```

En la consola de la aplicación al entrar a la vista donde uso la petición me aparece lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se si me hace falta alguna configuración extra o estoy usando mal el metodo fetch dentro de la aplicación de Shopify.
Agradeceria su ayuda.

Comment: Revisa donde envías la tienda, porque podría dejarte pasar y darte el según error pero si te regresa undefined básicamente no esta apuntando a nada.